# What is optimal number of tables we can use with JOINs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2012

I have a query which fetches records from 7 tables. All these tables are JOINed to get the details, few tables used multiple times with different ON clause. So there are 10 JOINs in the query. How can we optimize the query for getting better performance? We already have indexes on JOIN columns. Anything we can do to reduce the number of JOINs? Am using MS SQL 2012 with compatibility level 2008.

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 100
        MT.ProjectId, 
        matRef, 
        matDescription, 
        matKeyDescription, 
        matOpenDate, 
        matUFN, 
        matBranchRef, 
        matClosedDate, 
        ERN1.feeRef, 
        WorkTypeCode, 
        DPT.deptNo AS matDeptRef, 
        PreviousRef, 
        MT.ApplicationID, 
        MatterCompleted, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.PFCivil_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsCPF, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.PF_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsPF, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.Family_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsFM, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.WL_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsWills, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.Convey_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsConvey, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.Probate_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsProbate, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.PI_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsPi, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.PIPortal_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsPiPortal, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.CM_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsChest, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.Campaigns_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsMarketing, 
        CASE WHEN MLC.PFFamilyFixedFee_MatterCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsPFFamilyFixedFeeMatter, 
        ERN2.feeRef AS MatPartner, 
        MatPFCertificateNo, 
        CASE WHEN MT.matClosedDate = {d''1753-01-01''} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsArchived,
        '''' Modules,
        MT.ChargeDescID,
        MT.MatterTypeID, 
        PrimaryClient.ClientName, 
        MB.LastAccDate, 
        MB.LastBillDate, 
        MB.LastClientDate, 
        MB.LastTimeDate
    FROM dbo.Matter AS MT 
    JOIN dbo.Departments AS DPT ON DPT.deptID = MT.deptID 
    JOIN dbo.Earners AS ERN1 ON ERN1.MemberId = MT.MatFeeMemId 
    JOIN dbo.Earners AS ERN2 ON ERN2.MemberId = MT.matPartnerMemId 
    JOIN dbo.WorkTypes AS WT ON WT.WorkTypeID = MT.WorkTypeID 
    JOIN dbo.ivw_MatterLinkCount AS MLC ON MLC.ProjectId = MT.ProjectId 
    JOIN dbo.Banks AS ClientBank ON MT.matClientBank = ClientBank.bankID
    JOIN dbo.Banks AS OfficeBank ON MT.matOfficeBank = OfficeBank.bankID
    JOIN dbo.Banks AS DepositBank ON MT.matDepositBank = DepositBank.bankID
    JOIN uvw_MatterPrimaryClient AS PrimaryClient ON PrimaryClient.ProjectId = MT.ProjectId
    JOIN dbo.MatterBalance AS MB ON MT.ProjectId = MB.ProjectID
    WHERE  matDescription LIKE @Description 
    ORDER BY Isarchived, matRef
```

Comment: You should have indexes on fields from  WHERE clause, not on join columns. And post here actual plan, please

Comment: There is no way to optimize a query without looking at it, the specifics steps required to optimize your query will be specific to your query. In the general sense, apply the correct indexes to your tables.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Here is the query:

Comment: Make it part of your question.

Comment: Yes, I just did that.

Comment: You can't optimise a query by removing tables from it (i.e. reduce number of joins) unless you don't need data from those tables

Without looking at the query plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)  and DDL for the tables in questions it's hard to provide assistance

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that 'WHERE  matDescription LIKE @Description' is not the real filter.
The real filter is 'TOP 100' together with 'ORDER BY Isarchived, matRef' because this filter will absolutely filter out anything but 100 rows.
So you need an index at Isarchived, matRef too. Table scan for matRef probably delays this one.
Also unless the Isarchived, matRef combination is unique by constraint, you better add the PK at the end like ORDER BY Isarchived, matRef, matid so there would be no extra problem picking the top 100.
Finally, if Isarchived is something like 0/1 and you have tons of records with 0 value it is useless at order by as there would always be 0. Set it as a filter Isarchived = 0 and remove it from order by - use matRef, matid and add a single index to matRef only.